# “core exception: there was an error processing your order" PayPal

Tags: magento-1.6

I am facing this error when I try to place order in magento via using paypal payment method.

Error message is: `core exception: there was an error processing your order, Please contact us or try again later.`

Log error is..

```
2015-01-21T06:58:39+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal response hasn't required fields.' in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:972
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(649): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoDirectPayment', Array)
#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(343): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoDirectPayment()
#2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(202): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->_placeOrder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '128.41')
#3 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(408): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '128.41')
#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(378): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(569): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(375): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(317): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(856): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1074): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#10 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#14 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#15 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(767): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#16 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/FME/QuickCheckout/controllers/OnestepController.php(644): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#17 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): FME_QuickCheckout_OnestepController->saveOrderAction()
#18 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#19 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /var/www/magento/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

I am using magento 1.6.2.0 version. Please guide me what could the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response from the PayPal API saying that something is wrong. So please check your PayPal credentials. It could also be that the server is temporarily unavailable.